# ActiveAdmin unpermitted param on has many: through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I went through around 12 StackOverflow questions similar to this one but none of them seem to help me out.

Active admin:
Article.rb

```
permit_params tag_ids: []
...
f.input :tag, as: :check_boxes, collection: Tag.all.map { |h|  [h.name, h.id] }
```

Tag:

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :articles, through: :taggings
```

Taggings:

```
class Tagging < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

Article:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
```

I tried permitting the following:

- tag_ids:[]
- tag_ids: [:id]
- tag_attributes: [:id]

Getting:

```
found unpermitted parameter: hashtag
```

Something is missing!

UPD 1

Here's my log:

```
[INFO ] === Processing by Admin::ArticlesController#update as HTML
[INFO ]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "article"=>{"tag"=>["", "1", "2"] ...}, "commit"=>"Update Article", "id"=>"1"}
[DEBUG]   AdminUser Load (2.1ms)  SELECT  "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "admin_users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[DEBUG]   Article Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[DEBUG] Unpermitted parameter: tag
```

Comment: please add your server log for better understating.

Comment: @user100693 updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it. There are two options to achieve the desired result.

### Add/remove tags from AA dynamically.

Thanks for the hint from @user100693, by adding accepts_nested_attributes to my Article model I was able to add/remove the desired tags dynamically, however I had to add

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :taggings, allow_destroy: true` , NOT `:tags`

The permitted attributes were:

```
taggings_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :tag_id]
```

And the AA form code:

```
  f.has_many :taggings, allow_destroy: true, new_record: true do |h|
    h.input :tag
  end
```

### Multiple select checkboxes

This is the desired result I tried to achieve - assign articles to tags through checkboxes. Turned out that the only change I needed to do to my original code (see question) is this:

Active admin `Article.rb`

Permitted params: `tag_ids:[]`

Form: `f.input :tags, as: :check_boxes`

Instead of iterating over the `Hash`. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Firs of all, `accepts_nested_attributes_for` By adding this , `"article"=>{"tag"=>["", "1", "2"] ...}` will convert to `"article"=>{"tags_attributes"=>["", "1", "2"] ...}`

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :category
   has_many :taggings
   has_many :tags, through: :taggings

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

In your controller for Article,

add `tags_attributes: [:id]` in strong parameters list. This will solve your issue.

Happy Coding.

Comment: thank you, nothing changed, however. I am still getting the exact same output. My thoughts are that something might be wrong with my form.

Comment: Paste your updated logs of sever here. And confirm is it passing as tags_attributes not only tags.

Comment: Nothing changed in the logs. I did solve the issue however, the answer is below.